# Automate the Upload of a .bak file to Azure

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-sql-database, ssms

I'm very new to Azure and have been tasked with automating the process of taking an existing version of our database, converting it to the newer version and then uploading that to Azure.

The conversion is done, that parts easy, what I'm struggling with is getting a .bacpac file from SSMS using PowerShell. I know I can use the **Export Data Tier Application** function in SSMS to do this but I need it to be automated. From there I can use something like the following to actually upload the database:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2013/09/26/how-to-export-an-on-premises-sql-server-database-to-windows-azure-storage/

I have looked around and cannot find a solution to this, or even know where to start.

Comment: Try Microsoft Data Migration Assistant
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595

Comment: Also for scheduling you can use https://sqlbackupandftp.com/

Comment: Perfect, will i be able to runt he migration assistant from PowerShell with an args list?

Comment: Yes; you can make a bat file for with power shell commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create bacpac of your on-premises databases and locate them on a local folder (c:\MyBacpacs) using [SQLPackage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/01/31/using-sqlpackage-to-import-or-export-azure-sql-db/).

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Export /SourceServerName:. /sdn:"DB_Foo" /tf:"c:\MyBacpacs\DB_Foo.bacpac"
```

You can then use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) to upload bacpacs to Azure BLOB storage

```
AzCopy /Source:"c:\MyBacpacs" /Dest:"https://exampleaccount.blob.core.windows.net/bacpacs" /DestKey:storageaccountkey /Pattern:*.bacpac
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very easy to use.